# Normalize 2D matrix using scalar multiplication in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I have a matrix `thing` that looks like this:

```
thing.shape
(8070829, 2)
```

and I want to scale all elements by some `scalingfactor = np.iinfo(np.int16).max/thing.max()` to normalize the values. Right now I am iterating over all elements which works, but is really slow:

```
for j, sample in enumerate(thing):
    thing[j] = [int(sample[0] * scalingfactor), int(sample[1] * scalingfactor)]
```

I thought I could do the following, but the results are not the same:

```
np.multiply(thing, scalingfactor)
```

Is there are more efficient way to normalize a matrix?

Comment: Of course they aren't the same. In one case, you truncate the values. In the other, you don't.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I do not understand why one truncates (`int`?), the other does not.

Comment: You call `int` in the first case, right? You don't in the second. I'm assuming scalingFactor < 1.

Comment: I didn't mention it in my question, but I later also run `thing = thing.astype(np.int16, copy=False)` so either one will end up as ints. Shouldn't this have the same effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use vectorized elementwise multiplication and then change dtype (that does the `floor`-ing) -

```
(thing*scalingfactor).astype(int) # for thing as array type
```

Or use `np.floor` on the scaled version -

```
np.floor(thing*scalingfactor)
```

Using the posted code from the question : `np.multiply(thing, scalingfactor)` would work too, just needs the additional floor-ing step, as suggested earlier.

Comment: Ah, this worked! Thank you! I'll accept the answer once I can